# Css absolute position differs in Chrome and firefox in prestashop theme

Tags: css, css-position, prestashop

I'm fixing a prestashop theme and I'm about ready to tear my hair out over a very small issue. I have a search positioned absolutely beside my navigation, but the top is 10px lower than firefox in chrome, so  basically, if it is centered in firefox, it hangs low on chrome. below is my search box css:

```
#search_block_top {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
right: 20px;
top: 215px;/*this is correct in firefox*/
z-index: 1005;
}
```

you can see the site in here: http://goo.gl/sfFYT reset is given my stylesheet and I have tried manually setting search block's font-size and line-height to zero, but it hasn't worked. I have no idea what to do with this. Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Why are you using absolute positing at all?? Just put it in your `<div id="adtm_menu_inner">` div??

Comment: that div is being generated from a module. I don't like it either, but I have to work with what I've got!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't view the answer before mine, and gave a totally duplicated answer. withdraw that. and here is the new one:

```
#menu {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#search_block_top {
    top: 205px; /* you can modify the original rule */
}
```

the main idea: create a BFC for #menu with `overflow: hidden;`

PS: that code is unbelievable. :(

stay away from that, and have a nice day.

Comment: I'm going to try your code now. And this theme is supposed to be a premium one. I seriously think I have died and gone to hell!

Comment: actually, no, it doesn't work, because `overflow:hidden` hides the dropdown! anyway, thanks for the help. At least you got a solution!